# jQuery FancyBox initialisation not working

Tags: jquery, fancybox

So I have a gallery of photos looking like this:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <a href="thumb1.jpg" class="fancybox">
    <img class="item"  src="thumb1.jpg">
  </a>
  ...
</div>
```

I initialise fancybox on my image links like so...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

...but nothing happens - clicking the images in my gallery simply links to the href'd image.

I get no errors from the Chrome console, and `jQuery('.fancybox')` correctly selects all my `<a>` elements.

Any ideas why fancybox seemingly does not work?

Comment: Check that the `.fancybox` method exists on the jQuery object; you may be importing the plugin incorrectly. If it doesn't, make sure you include `<script>` tags to reference the correct location.

Comment: `fancybox` is present in the `__proto__` of the object returned by `jQuery('.fancybox')`, so I believe the plugin is imported alright.

Comment: Which version of FancyBox?  [This old one](http://fancybox.net/) or [this new one](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)?  A lot was changed between versions.

Comment: @Sparky Versions got me thinking about my jQuery version, which it turns out was too low (1.4.4). Updated to 1.8.2 and now it works. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest versions of FancyBox and jQuery.

Comment: @KarlBarker : ironically I suggested you to load the latest version of jQuery in the point No.1 of my answer 5 hours ago (the attached fiddle also loads the latest version)... well, such is life.

Answer (score 5):

Your check list (load the files in this order) :

1. Load jQuery js file first. Make sure you have a single instance of this file, ideally the latest version (some other plugins include a version of jQuery that is loaded when the plugin is installed)
2. Load your fancybox's js and css files. Check that the (full) paths are correct (if you explore the source code and click on the links of those files, you should see the source script, otherwise the html of an error 404 page).
3. Load your custom fancybox script. Also check that all your `<script>` tags are inside of either, the `<head>` or the `<body>` tags (I have seen some code where the scripts are in between)
4. Last, check that your document has a proper `DOCTYPE`. Also check for syntax errors and tags not properly closed.

See a **[full example](http://jsfiddle.net/3JWL6/)** with the same initialization as in your code above.